# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mypred' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, html, flask

so I have tried to fix this internal server error for a few days now for a personal project and when I debug just says "NameError: name 'pred' is not defined". I have looked at other posts and such, but I haven't had any luck so far. Here is the code I have written:

```
!pip install flask-ngrok

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
run_with_ngrok(app)   

def cloud_prediction(time):
  model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
  return float(model.forecast(time)[0][time-1])

@app.route("/", methods= ["GET", "POST"])
def final():
  if request.method =="POST":
    time = int(request.form["time"])
    global pred
    pred = cloud_prediction(time)
    mypred= pred
    print(mypred)
  return render_template("index.html", name= mypred)


if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run()
```

My index.html file is saved in a folder named templates, and it looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>WeatherNexus Inc.</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A fortune teller for cloud activity.">
  <meta name="author" content="Jesus_Lopez">

  <meta property="og:title" content="WeatherNexus Inc.">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:description" content="A fortune teller for cloud activity.">
  
</head>

<body>
  <body bgcolor='black' text='white'>
  <h1>WeatherNexus Inc.<h1>
    <p>
     <font size=15 class="text-center">
     Please input the time when you want to predict the cloud coverage. Timesteps are in 5 min increments. Ex: 6 = 30min

    </p>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
      <input type="number" name="time" placeholder="Input Time here">
      <input type="submit">
      <p>Here is your residual output: </p>{{name}}
    </form>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is, if I take "name = mypred" out of the render_template command, then the variable gets defined and prints in the notebook, but I'd like to print the result in the webpage not just in my notebook.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: question: why create a global var and assign to a local if it's only used in that scope? Why not just assign `mypred` immediately?

Comment: It was one thing I tried to fix my problem. Originally, I didnt use it as a global variable. It give the same error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mypred' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Ah, on second glance you're only setting `mypred` if the request method is POST. Either move the render_template, change the request method, or define `mypred` before the request method check.

Comment: Yea I just saw that too. I fixed it by:                                                          
@app.route("/", methods= ['GET'])
def home():
  return render_template('index.html')

Comment: Thanks for looking over my code Phix!

Comment: Anytime Jesse, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/", methods= ['GET'])
def home():
  return render_template('index.html')
```

This was needed before my final definition.